# How to do synchronous scrolling for ten gridView in one LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-gridview

I have two gridView the same size. How to do synchronous scrolling.
Could I disable gridView scrolling and enable LinearLayout scrolling?

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="1080dp"
     android:layout_height="700dp"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     >
     <GridView
         android:id="@+id/gridView1"
         android:layout_width="60dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:numColumns="1"
         >
     </GridView>
     <GridView
         android:id="@+id/gridView2"
         android:layout_width="240dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:numColumns="1" >
     </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Could I disable gridView scrolling and enable LinearLayout scrolling?
```

for this question.No.there is another more effective way.

GridView is provided the [smoothScrollToPosition(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) or [setSelection(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setSelection%28int%29) method via its AbsLisView parent. This will scroll to the position you desire. Now, you should listen for ScrollEvent with the [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html).

Now just add these code together:

```
GridView other;
@Override public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstItem, int visItems, int total) {
   other.smoothScrollToPosition(firstItem);
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: But smoothScrollToPosition doesn't work, I used setSelection(). Thank you.